# How to select only content in the sheet rather all unused/empty cell value

Tags: c#, vba, excel, c#-4.0

My goal is to load the excel(only one sheet) data to DataTable. so that i have used the following query.

```
                 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet custdataset;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new OleDbConnection
                {
                    ConnectionString = ConnectionString(filename, "Yes")
                };

                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                custdataset = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(custdataset);
                MyConnection.Close();
```

but it load the all unused/empty cell value to datatable. how to avoid that? how to load only used cell value. For example A1 to F4 not whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string filepath)
{
    // string sqlquery= "Select * From [SheetName$] Where YourCondition";
    string sqlquery = "Select * From [SheetName$] Where Id='ID_007'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring + "");
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```

you can use this one, if it match

Comment: Its not woking.. Thanks for your reply